# Concatenate Siamese Neural Net in Tensorflow from Scratch: mismatch in shape

Tags: tensorflow

I'm developing a Siamese Neural Net in Tensorflow with the following code:

```
X = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32)
X2 = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32)
Y = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32)

num_hidden=128

# Build a hidden layer Left
W_hidden = tf.Variable(tf.random.normal([784, num_hidden]))
b_hidden = tf.Variable(tf.random.normal([num_hidden]))
p_hidden = tf.nn.relu( tf.add(tf.matmul(X, W_hidden), b_hidden) )

W_hidden2 = tf.Variable(tf.random.normal([num_hidden, num_hidden]))
b_hidden2 = tf.Variable(tf.random.normal([num_hidden]))
p_hidden2 = tf.nn.relu( tf.add(tf.matmul(p_hidden, W_hidden2), b_hidden2) )

# Build a hidden layer Right
W_hiddenR = tf.Variable(tf.random.normal([784, num_hidden]))
b_hiddenR = tf.Variable(tf.random.normal([num_hidden]))
p_hiddenR = tf.nn.relu( tf.add(tf.matmul(X2, W_hiddenR), b_hiddenR) )

W_hidden2R = tf.Variable(tf.random.normal([num_hidden, num_hidden]))
b_hidden2R = tf.Variable(tf.random.normal([num_hidden]))
p_hidden2R = tf.nn.relu( tf.add(tf.matmul(p_hiddenR, W_hidden2R), b_hidden2R) )

# Conncatenate Left + Right
W_concat = tf.Variable(tf.random.normal([1000, num_hidden]))
b_concat = tf.Variable(tf.random.normal([num_hidden]))
p_concat2 = tf.nn.relu(tf.add(tf.matmul(tf.add(p_hidden2,p_hidden2R), W_concat), b_concat))

# Build the output layer
W_output = tf.Variable(tf.random.normal([num_hidden, 10]))
b_output = tf.Variable(tf.random.normal([10]))
p_output = tf.nn.softmax( tf.add(tf.matmul(p_concat2, W_output), b_output))

loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.losses.mean_squared_error(
        labels=Y,predictions=p_output))
accuracy=1-tf.sqrt(loss)

minimization_op = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=0.001).minimize(loss)
saver = tf.train.Saver()

def norm(x):
    return (x-np.min(x))/(np.max(x)-np.min(x))

feed_dict = {
    X: norm(x_train[0:1000].reshape(-1,784)),X2: norm(x_train[0:1000].reshape(-1,784)),
    Y: pd.get_dummies(y_train[0:1000])
}

with tf.Session() as session:
    session.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

    for step in range(8000):
        J_value = session.run(loss, feed_dict)
        acc = session.run(accuracy, feed_dict)
        if step % 100 == 0:
            print("Step:", step, " Loss:", J_value," Accuracy:", acc)
            session.run(minimization_op, feed_dict)
    pred00 = session.run([p_output], feed_dict={X: x_test.reshape(-1,784)})
```

However, I'm getting the following error:

```
InvalidArgumentError: 2 root error(s) found.
  (0) Invalid argument: In[0] mismatch In[1] shape: 128 vs. 1000: [1000,128] [1000,128] 0 0
     [[{{node MatMul_147}}]]
     [[Mean_41/_25]]
  (1) Invalid argument: In[0] mismatch In[1] shape: 128 vs. 1000: [1000,128] [1000,128] 0 0
     [[{{node MatMul_147}}]]
0 successful operations.
0 derived errors ignored.
```

Any ideas on how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will answer my question: I solved the issue, the Neural Net is training now. The error refers to `MatMul` operation where a  `[1000,128]` matrix was trying to multiply by `[1000,128]`. As I want a 1000 x 128 output, I had to multiply `[1000,128]` `[128,128]` given that `[m,n]` x `[n,p]` will generate a `[m,p]` output.